# How to prevent large inrush current without a reset-fuse

Tags: inrush-current

In another question ([DC-DC booster fails with lead-acid battery source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/379929/dc-dc-booster-fails-with-lead-acid-battery-source)) I described a problem with a DC-DC booster that destroyed itself by dragging a large current when its output was disconnected.

This did not happend when the power source was a sw-mode (maybe due to its overload circuit), but when a Lead-acid battery was used who could deliver large burst current (>40A).

Apparantly this is a consequence of the DC-booster design. So I need some shut-off circuit which could be a resettable fuse, but I think that this is somewhat a primitive solution.

Maybe its possible to use some power FET, but im not much into how to design control a shut-off state at, say at 8A - and certainly not to make it well working.

Comment: Unless he can implement a soft start in the regulator a solution could be an “ICL surge limiter” for startup only but for cutoff UVP is needed or switch the input to Reg

Comment: Resistor + relay. But soft start is way better.

Comment: Inrush? Maybe flyback protection from inductive wire current?

Comment: I could put another of the same DC-booster in front of the original that could limit the current of the original that want to destroy itself (both have pots for controlling the current). The front DC-DC will never have its output disconnected as it feeds the original ;)

Comment: Or maybe a couple of LM317 in current limiter mode. I think I can remember this shown in the fab. specs

Comment: No 317! Google boost inrush current and you will find plenty of examples. My precious design had NTC+relay in parallel and a by-pass diode over the entire boost converter to take the hit there to the output cap.

Comment: yaya - But its not inrush current I want to prevent, but disconnect-rush (or is it the same)

Comment: It seems to me that the main problem is the converter doing something odd when you disconnect the load - does the converter have a schematic or data sheet?

Comment: Andy - It a cheap china PCB build with a Texas PWM chip. It *is* smart and works very well (96% efficency) but have this "little" flaw. I guess its just not complete with protection and probably intended for use with sw-mode as power source. So its no that "odd" other than You need to add some limiter when using LA batts.