# Who can show a schematic for a voltage switch

Tags: current, dc-dc-converter

In earlier questions I raised a problem about a DC-DC booster that destroyed itself when its load was disconnected by drawing a large current from its input power source. This was specific when using Lead-Acid batteries (probably because a LA can deliver a large burst).

The task was (for me) to find a current-limiter solution on the input. I have tried a simple solution with a resettable (push) fuse, but that is too slow.

I have then found this device, based on a **Allegro** current sensor **ACS712**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

*With this I can get a corresponding voltage reading from its current flowthrough.*

So here we go. How do I use some external discrete components to activate a relay that disconnect the input power to the DC-booster? I know about electronics - but not that much. My simple guess is a zener that controls a transistor that powers the relay. But it must be good (with good I mean quick acting) and reliable.

From the curve, I can see that the wanted breaking point is around 3,2V at 6-7Ampere (It must break from 6A and up).

Below, links to my earlier questions about this problem

[Fuses - Are there any voltage conversion for the break-off](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383713/fuses-are-there-any-voltage-conversion-for-the-break-off)

[How to prevent large inrush current without a reset-fuse](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383120/how-to-prevent-large-inrush-current-without-a-reset-fuse)

[DC-DC booster fails with lead-acid battery source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/379929/dc-dc-booster-fails-with-lead-acid-battery-source)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4eUei.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: NTC (+relay) didn’t work out for you?

Comment: winny - Im sorry, but I didnt really take Your suggestion into account. I did not understand the idea, but is it really that simple?
A NTC is about sensing temperature, and at that point I guess its too late...

Comment: NTC’s are also called ICL protective chips

Comment: An NTC (stands for negative temperature coefficient) starts out at higher resistance when cold to limit the current.  As it heats up the resistance drops to avoid excess losses.  So yes, it "is about sensing temperature" (its own) and it is not "too late" because it STARTS at higher resistance.

Comment: The NTC idea sounds good then. But I am talking about a load of 17V/ 5A and a breaking current from 6A. As far I can see, there is not thermistors for such currents...

Comment: Diode is reversed. Put it with cathode upwards

Comment: Stop scratching for thermistors. You can find NTCs for inrush current limiting for almost any arbitrary value.

Comment: I think the only company that makes the ACS712 is Allegro, isn't it? Not Texas. Not that that's relevant to the question.

Comment: Winny - NTC'S for currents like this, typically have 10 Ohm resistance. So this give me a glowing part by P= R*I2 =10*5*5 = 250Watt. A bad idea. If such problems could be solved by a simple NTC, then circuits like the current sensor ACS712 above would be redundant - right ! btw: what is Your electronics background since You suggest such an bad idea..